# How can i create a fully generic home page using blazor that will render dynamically its content depending on the backend data?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, blazor, blazor-webassembly

we have 3 desktop software that have the same home page layout with the same components layout ,they differentiate in the data that is displayed depending on each software , My task is to create a Generic home page having the same layout ( i made the layout ) and to use RenderFragment to dynamically render each UI component depending on data coming from backend ( using services )

i have code like this :

```
protected RenderFragment createVignettes() => builder =>{

List<Vignette> listeVignettes = new List<Vignette>{new Vignette { Content="first", Header="Icon+colour"}} ; 

int count = listeVignettes.Count();

builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(TileLayout));

builder.AddAttribute(0, "numberofColumns", count);

builder.AddAttribute(1, "Tile_layout_title", "Liste des vignettes");

builder.AddAttribute(2, "childComponents", listeVignettes);builder.CloseComponent();};

public partial class TileLayout  {

public partial  class Vignette {

        public String Header { get; set; }       
        public String Content { get; set; }     }  
   [Parameter]     public int numberofColumns { get; set; }   
   [Parameter]     public string Tile_layout_title { get; set; }   
   [Parameter]     public List<Vignette> childComponents { get; set; }  = new List<Vignette>();
```

this is the code of one component !! my work doesn't look professional and precise , each " vignette " will have an svg and colour variables coming from the services , i didn't know how to do that !! we are using telerik UI , i am not getting into making all details generic , I need ideas or even architectural ideas how to make it fully generic my home page !! , it will be rendered dynamically depending on data coming from endpoints ! I have to use generic types also if needed !

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/ModelToComponent I did this 3 years ago before dynamic component existed.